# I have 6 projects running on Heroku, and one of then is getting traction. Now I want to buy a Dyno. How many apps can run on a single Dyno?

Tags: heroku, dyno

Can I run the app gaining traction on a purchased Dyno and the rest 5 apps on the free Dyno?

Also the billing, for a single Dyno will it be exactly $7 or vary with the use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can upgrade only one of your apps to paid dynos, and keep all the other apps on free dynos. Your monthly quota of [free dyno hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours) is per your heroku account, not per an individual app. So your 5 low-traction apps will simply share your 1000 free dyno hours per month. (Note that your quota will be 1000 free dyno hours per month, since you definitely will have [verified your account](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification) in order to upgrade your high-traction app to paid dynos).

As for the exact charge: If your high traction app uses only a single [Hobby Dyno](https://www.heroku.com/pricing) and NO other non-free-tier [add-ons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons), then your bill will be exactly $7 / month, and will not vary with use.

Comment: This was really helpful. Thanlk you.